# Get multiple attributes from one node

Tags: c#, html, image, alt

I'm trying to extract two attributes from one img node but there is a `NullReferenceException`, the highlighted line isn't working and i can't figure out why:

```
var imageCollection = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img");
foreach (HtmlNode imageNode in imageCollection)
{
    var imageLink = imageNode.Attributes["src"].Value;
    var something=imageNode.Attributes["alt"].Value; // !!!

    if (Regex.IsMatch(imageLink, "1280.jpg"))
    {
        urls.Add(imageLink);
        //Date.Add(something);
    }
}
```

and the html code:

```
<img src="imageurl" alt="http://bbc.in/ZWwFHt" width="610" height="610">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your images do not have `alt` attribute. Check if it is null.

```
var alt = imageNode.Attributes["alt"];
if(alt!=null)
{
    var something = alt.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i'am getting an error saying that HtmlagilityaPack doesn't contain a definition for value...

Comment: @GregoireDumas A typo. I edited the answer. it should be `Value`, not `value`.